# Datatable in background in cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

How would I create a data table in the background and access its data in the scenario?

I am running scenarios with variations of values ​​and data and would like to know if I can access the values ​​entered in a backgorund table

```
Background:
```

> ```
> Given Essas informacoes:
>   | Price | Name | Insurance     | Damage           | Type     | Email |
>   |       |      |  3.000.000,00 | Full Coverage    | Gold     |       |
>   |       |      | 10.000.000,00 | No Coverage      | Silver   |       |
>   |       |      | 25.000.000,00 | Partial Coverage | Platinum |       |
>   |       |      |               |                  | Ultimate |       |
>   |       |      |               |                  |          |       |
> And E o navegador aberto
> And O site carregado
> And Tendo selecionado Truck
> ```

```
@ValidarCotas  
Scenario: Selecionar cotacao de seguro de tipo diferente de acordo com valores variados
        Given Esta na tela do formulario de Truck
        And Preenchido os dados do veiculo e os dados do segurado
        When Preencho os campos do formulario de dados do seguro  "**<Insurance>**" "**<Damage>**"
        And Seleciono cota de seguro "<Type>"
        Then Valido se a cota foi enviada para o email
        And Valido se o valor da cota for o mesmo que eu selecionei no site
        When Fecho o navegador
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is an English site. Although other spoken languages are allowed in code where it is possible to answer the question without knowing the language, that does not appear to be the case in this question. Please either edit your question to be answerable by only knowing English or close and re-ask this question on the version of Stack Overflow for your native language. Thanks!

Comment: Use this link to Stack Exchange sites that include questions in non-English languages >>> https://stackexchange.com/sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to reuse your examples across multiple scenarios. AFAIK it is not supported when using gherkin with cucumber.

One of the way is to reuse examples between scenarios by moving examples in external file and referencing it in your scenario which is supported using [gherkin with qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) or [BDD2 with qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd2.html) but not cucumber.

For example:

```
Background: 
Given E o navegador aberto
And O site carregado
And Tendo selecionado Truck

@ValidarCotas
@dataFile:resources/data/testdata.csv   
Scenario: Selecionar cotacao de seguro de tipo diferente de acordo com valores variados
        Given Esta na tela do formulario de Truck
        And Preenchido os dados do veiculo e os dados do segurado
        When Preencho os campos do formulario de dados do seguro  "**<Insurance>**" "**<Damage>**"
        And Seleciono cota de seguro "<Type>"
        Then Valido se a cota foi enviada para o email
        And Valido se o valor da cota for o mesmo que eu selecionei no site
        When Fecho o navegador
```

Refer [documentation](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd2.html#data-driven-scenario) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "Scenario Outline" here, it can be used to run the same Scenario multiple times, with different combinations of values.

```
Scenario Outline: eating
  Given there are <start> cucumbers
  When I eat <eat> cucumbers
  Then I should have <left> cucumbers

  Examples:
    | start | eat | left |
    |    12 |   5 |    7 |
    |    20 |   5 |   15 |
```

Use Background if you have multiple repeatable "Given" steps in each test case.

Comment: But the values ​​are common for various scenarios.

Comment: Then, I don't understand your question. You have one scenario right? With multiple values? if yes, use Scenario Outline. Why u need to use Background here?

Comment: I have 3 scenarios where they use the same values, I wonder if I could use the data table for these 3 scenarios?

Comment: Can u add all three scenarios, but translate it first